# How to integrate apple pay in react js without using stripe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, applepay, applepayjs

I want to integrate apple pay in our project using Cybersource but due to lack of documentation, I didn't get any way to integrate the apple pay button on our website and I am a little confused about some methods like canMakePayment, canMakePaymentWithActiveCards, PaymentRequest, and how are they available in window DOM.
Please let me know the correct way to integrate it.